# Ler e explorar arquivos dat através do R

Tags: r

Pessoal estou com um arquivo dat: "dadodat"

Como faço para abri-lo no R e explora-lo?

Comment: Um arquivo .dat pode ser qualquer coisa, acho que é o formato mais genérico que existe. Se for de texto com uma tabela, basta verificar qual é o formato do arquivo e usar as funções de leitura de tabelas (`read.table` e similares). Se for de texto com outros estilos (tipo xml) ou binário, só faz sentido se você souber qual é a origem e existir um pacote para R que faça essa leitura.

Comment: Abre o arquivo com o notepad e cola as primeiras linhas ou uma imagem. Assim será mais fácil tentar te ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traduzindo e adaptando a resposta [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664075/import-dat-file-into-r).

**Primeiro:**

Como um arquivo `.dat` pode armazenar qualquer tipo de dado, antes de importá-lo pela 1ª vez é útil utilizar `readLines` para ler as primeiras linhas do arquivo, para que assim você consiga identificar o que é o cabeçalho dos dados, daquilo que realmente é o dado:

```
readLines("http://www.nilu.no/projects/ccc/onlinedata/ozone/CZ03_2009.dat", 
          n=10)
# [1] "Ozone data from CZ03 2009"   "Local time: GMT + 0"        
# [3] ""                            "Date        Hour      Value"
# [5] "01.01.2009 00:00       34.3" "01.01.2009 01:00       31.9"
# [7] "01.01.2009 02:00       29.9" "01.01.2009 03:00       28.5"
# [9] "01.01.2009 04:00       32.9" "01.01.2009 05:00       20.5"
```

a partir desse conjunto dados, é possível identificar que os dados de fato começam a partir da 4ª linha e estão em formato de tabela. Então basta fazer:

**Resposta Rápida:**

```
read.table("http://www.nilu.no/projects/ccc/onlinedata/ozone/CZ03_2009.dat", 
           header=TRUE, skip=3)
```

Caso o dado não tivesse em formato de tabela, tu poderia utilizar outra função para importar, como alguma das funções genéricas do `read.?`